# Why are both "since I went ..." and "since I've been ..." OK?

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I've just done an exercise. It is:

> A: How often do you go to the cinema?
> B: Very rarely. It's nearly a year ___________ to the cinema.

And the answer is "since I've been / since I went". (both OK)
I'm confusing why "since I've been" is OK.

1. Since **since** refers to a situation in the past, why is it correct that present perfect is here?
2. is there any difference in meaning between "since I've been" and "since I went"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Strictly speaking there is a literal difference, but there is no difference at all in meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"It's nearly a year since I went..." you are thinking of the last time you went, i.e. a specific action completed in the past. "It's nearly a year since I've been..." you are thinking of the time span you haven't been, so present perfect, an action that has been performed (in this case hasn't been performed) for a period starting in the past continuing to the present.
But in reality, here they have the same meaning.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to learn a lot.